# Is it possible to has more than 1 @WithMockUser in one test method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reflection, junit5

I am using Spring boot + Spring Security + Junit 5, latest version.

Is it possible that in one testing method, I can use two @WithMockUser() ? So the testing method run two times and each time with different @WithMockUser information? For example, I have

```
@WithMockUser(username="admin",roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
@WithMockUser(username="user" ,roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
public void test1() {}
```

Equals run two times. like:

```
@WithMockUser(username="admin",roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
public void test1() {}
```

and

```
@WithMockUser(username="user" ,roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
public void test1() {}
```

Java source code solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UserRequestPostProcessor` to configure `MockMvc` request to achieve the equivalent behaviour of `@WithMockUser`.

Together with Junit5 's parameterised test , you can do something like :

```java
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;
import static org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.of;


@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("withMockUser")
void someTest(String username, String[] roles) throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(get("/foo")         
           .with(user(username).roles(roles)))
           .......
}

private static Stream<Arguments> withMockUser() {
    return Stream.of(
            of("admin", new String[]{"USER", "ADMIN"}),
            of("user", new String[]{"USER", "ADMIN"})
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something similar with the [JUnit5 `@Nested` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-nested-test-classes) and inheritance - you can write `test1` once and have it run with both users. For example:

```java
public class MultipleMockUserTest {
    // No @Nested annotation here
    static class UserAndAdminTests {
        @Test
        void test1() {}
    }

    @Nested
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = {"USER", "ADMIN"})
    class UserTests extends UserAndAdminTests {}

    @Nested
    @WithMockUser(username = "admin", roles = {"USER", "ADMIN"})
    class AdminTests extends UserAndAdminTests {}
}
```

Comment: Sorry late reply. No, it is not even near to the solution